# Checking if String ends with something with Java (Regex)

Tags: java, regex

I need to know whether check whether a String end with something like .xyz plus any characters after it.

Like this:

```
myString.endsWidth(".css*")
```

However this does not pass my if-statement. One concrete example is this kind of string: `style.css?v=a1b23`

Any ideas?

**Complete example String:**

```
http://xyz.com//static/css/style.css?v=e9b34
```

Comment: endsWith doesn't use regular expressions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

hum, I am guessing something like this is even better:

```
return myString.indexOf(".css")>-1;
```

If you really want to go with regexp, you could use this

```
return myString.matches(".*?\\.css.*");
```

Comment: Just tried: "style.css?v=a1b23".matches(".*?\\.css.*") and it returns 'true' so you must have another issue somewhere

Answer (score 3):

`endsWith` takes a string as parameter

`matches` takes a regular expression

Answer (score 2):

Use `".*\.css.+"` as your regular expression.

Comment: I'm not sure where this does not work too? The complete string would be something like: http://xyz.com//static/css/style.css?v=e9b34

Comment: Did you consider Eric's answer? You need to use `match(String)`, not `endsWith(String)`. Updated the expression by the way.

Answer (score 0):

use `\.(.{3})(.*)` then the first group ($1) contains the three characters after `.` and the second group $2 contains the rest of the string after those three characters. Add a $ sign at the end of the expression to make it only look for strings ending with that combination

Answer (score 0):

Try some regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\.css.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("mystring"); 
if (m.matches()) {
    // do your stuff
}
```